# Как правильно отобразить изображение и видео с Youtube из RSS внутри TextView?

Tags: android, xml, rss

Я загружаю статью из RSS. В статье внутри текста могут присутствовать изображения, видео с Youtube. Проблема в том, что вместо изображений появляются синие квадраты, при нажатии на которые можно открыть полное фото в браузере. Видео вообще не отображается.

Я раздумываю над путём правильного отображения этих элементов. У меня есть 2 идеи:

1) Отобразить картинки с помощью ImageSpan прямо внутри TextView.
[Ответ на английском StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561981/how-to-display-image-in-androids-textview). Но что тогда делать с видео непонятно.

2) Разделять текст с помощью регулярного выражения на кусочки с непосредственно текстом, изображением или видео и отображать статью в RecyclerView.

Какой из этих путей будет наиболее оптимальным, или может быть есть какой-нибудь ещё способ?

Пример текста статьи:

```
<description>
В рамках проекта &lt;a href=&quot;https://github.com/galaxyhaxz
/devilution&quot;&gt;Devilution&lt;/a&gt; развивается альтернативный
вариант классической компьютерной ролевой игры &lt;a href=&quot;
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diablo_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0)&quot;&gt;Diablo
&lt;/a&gt;, выпущенной в 1996 году компанией  Blizzard Entertainment,
который можно использовать с набором ресурсов от оригинальной игры.
При создании проекта энтузиасты провели обратный инжиниринг  Diablo с использованием 
нескольких утечек кода из разных источников и отладочных файлов, которые были забыты в одной из поставок.     
&lt;center&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://camo.githubusercontent.com/9426dfe5fc03654a8f1d3c024019cd7c5fb468b6/68747470733a2f2f7333332e706f7374696d672e63632f36786e6e68686c6d6e2f6469616275
696d6f6e2e706e67?a.png&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/pics_base/0_1529402845.png&quot; style=&quot;border-style: solid;
border-color: #e9ead6; border-width: 15px;max-width:100%;&quot; title=&quot;&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/center&gt;                  &lt;p&gt;Собрав воедино имеющиеся в открытом доступе сведения энтузиасты поставили перед собой цель как можно более точно воссоздать исходный код и 
функциональность игры. Ожидается, что воссоздание исходных кодов возродит интерес к игре, упростит создание модификаций и позволит портировать игру для новых платформ.    &lt;center&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;https://camo.githubusercontent.com/c1b4f8890a676b46fe2b5cae7764c9fae252c7b2
/68747470733a2f2f7332322e706f7374696d672e63632f7a3866687575746b312f6469616273
746f72652e706e67?a.png&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;https://www.opennet.ru/opennews/pics_base/0_1529403761.png&quot; style=&quot;border-style: solid; border-color: #e9ead6; border-width: 15px;max-width:100%;&quot; title=&quot;&quot; border=0&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/center&gt;  
&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;Источник: &lt;b&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=48803&quot;&gt;http://www.opennet.ru/opennews/art.shtml?num=48803&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/b&gt;
</description>
```

Comment: а не получится это сделать через WebView? правда с оптимизацией производительности придется повозиться... да и размеры придется на лету менять (у рисунков/видео)... делал так в одном проекте - правда там было отображение html, тоже с рисунками и видео из разных источников (youtube/vimeo/twitter.....)

Comment: Обычно делали так - в списке показываем только текстовую информацию, возможно иконки что есть видео и изображения, в detail view уже используем WebView, желательно чтобы оно занимало весь экран (прячем хидер), иначе много проблем с масштабированием и-или скроллингом на разных версиях.